# how to mock an outside init of aws lambda function that execute on the beginning of the module?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, pytest, pytest-mock

Consider I have the following import in a pytest file:

```
from xyz import lambda_handler
```

But in xyz.py

We have:

```
def foo_init():
    return 1. 

x = foo_init()
def lambda_handler():
   # doing some logic and using x above
```

now in my pytest file:

I want to test function `lambda_handler`, so I need to import it, as a result of importing I get x = foo_init() executed.
So I want to mock the `foo_init()` part which is executed with the import when I do the import the lambda_handler in my pytest file.

Please note that it is **common** to have outside of the lambda_handler one time initializations **outside** of the lambda_handler scope which is called multiple times each time lambda is triggered.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest a pytest mock for this, mocking `foo_init()` so it is not actually called.  I see you have that tag added; what have you tried?

Comment: I got some weird exception in the mocking, instead of neutrilizing the function and let her return the expected values it try to access some inner logic and actually fetch data from s3 bucket.